# Where are the toys?

Tags: chibi-robo-zip-lash

I'm edging very close to 100%ing this game but, somehow, I seem to be missing the toys for world 4 and 5 entirely. I have almost every snack, chibi tot and big coin from those worlds, but never saw the wormhole.

I know the toy locations are somewhat random after finding them, but is there any simple way to find them for the first time? They're marked on the map after, but I've beaten both worlds and see no hints, and I already replayed half of world 5 with no luck too.

Answer (score 1):

I found the world 5 toy in 5-4.

I basically took advantage of the re-spawning enemies until I had a zip lash of 36.8, then I went down the pit and stood in front of the outlet to the left and zipped onto an orange pad above to a hidden spot.

Answer (score -1):

Complete 2 levels in world five, the next level you enter, the wormhole will take place of a diamond coin